# Why are the rules for calling ctors and dtors not symmetrical?

Tags: constructor, destructor, c++14

In order to call a constructor on an already allocated memory, we use placement new:

```
new(pMemory) Widget;
```

However, destructors seem to be directly callable:

```
pWidget->~Widget();
```

<sub>Soctt Meyars More Effective C++ item 8</sub>

Is this still valid with current C++ standard? What is the reason for this asymmetry?

Comment: What asymmetry? What would you propose as a 'symmetrical' version?

Comment: To be either able to directly call a constructor on some uninitiolized memory `static_cast<pWidget>(pMemory)->Widget();` OR need a trick to call any destructor as well.

Comment: Here's the reasoning: [link](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete)